# Python's IDLE support for the blind is lacking - Am I missing something?

Tags: python, python-idle

I like Python.  I like IDLE. I use python and IDLE to teach programming to to sighted and non-sighted people.  There are other python programming/learning interfaces available e.g. Eclipse with PyDev plugin, pyCharm.  I use IDLE rather than others because my students only have to download one thing - Python which includes, among other things, IDLE, Turtle, Tkinter.  For the beginner, I want to keep the impediments to a absolute minimum.

My blind students' problem with IDLE is that execution output is not spoken:

```
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
2+2
4
```

The "4" is not spoken.

- For clarificaion:
  My students use the JAWS program which catches text and the text is translated into spoken sounds. IDLE's program output is not spoken.

Our workaround for interactive python is to use python directly.  Example:

```
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2+2
4
>>>
```

In which the "4", as well as the other text, is spoken.

**I might be missing something.  If so please let me know.  As it is, we use python directly for interactive work and IDLE to do file based programs.**

To verbalize the program's output we have to select and copy the output window's text, switch to a Notepad program window and paste the results which are then spoken.

Even program editing, in a IDLE file window is difficult for my blind students.  They currently prefer to, from the IDLE file window, select, copy, switch to Notepad, paste, make edits, select, copy, switch to IDLE file window, select ALL(to enable overwriting the old contents), paste, then run the program.  Even so, IDLE is still useful for program development.

Comment: OT: I'm curious: how do blind people deal with Python's significant whitespace? Is it spoken, too?

Comment: [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look for information yourself](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+idle+screen+reader)?

Comment: IDLE lets one adjust window size, font, font size, and highlight colors so one can customize to taste or for people visually impaired, necessity.  But IDLE is based on the tkinter interface to tcl/tk and as far as I know, tk does not support screen readers.  I wish it were otherwise.  @crs, If you find something that works better, please let me know.  You say output is not read; is input read?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel OP has a screen reader that works with the Windows Console, used by Command Prompt, but only somewhat or not at all with the tk Text used by IDLE.  Searching "python idle screen reader" with Google or DuckDuckGo (Bing) returns hits about either IDLE or screen readers or neither but none about both (that I saw).   I suggested why above.

Comment: To Karl,  Thanks for the interest.  First, if I put my user hat on where difficulty is no excuse :), I'm just stating a sad observation,  I would hope that the software maintainers would "find a way" to solve the problem.  I'm asking my helpers at the school  - Perkins School for the Blind, to answer your questions about speaking the input.  I have no direct access to JAWS software to test this out (till next week's class).  Finding another IDE/tool or writing one's own is an option but as said - I Iike IDLE and whish it were better in this regard. Accessibility - ramps for the handicapped...

Comment: To Karl, An update: I just downloaded the free NVDA screen reader.  It works "out of the box".  As for IDLE: IDLE's shell: Input keystrokes are spoken.  However, output as well as IDLE's prompts, and error messages are not spoken.

Comment: I believe you meant to direct your last two comments to me.  To respond to a particular person, start with 'at sign' as I did above for Karl, type a couple of letters of the name, and click the popup.  Anyway, thank you.  I looked at NDVA docs.  I also found two question answers (SO and elsewhere) that tkinter (I presume Tk) does not provide needed accessibility info as of a year ago.  One questioner suggested that 'object navigate' might work somewhat but I do not know what he meant.  I may someday try out NVDA and experiment with a couple of ideas.

Comment: mkrieger1  re: The blind handling of Python whitespace:  As my students are very new to programming and Python, I can't say in general.  But my experience with the Braile software showed an interesting case of "Unintended consequences".  I am developing a "graphics to braille" Turtle Braille which converts simple Turtle output for blind viewing. (github raysmith619/resource_lib/readme.md)  The software compresses multiple blanks.  To avoid this, my software converts non-trailing blanks to commas(one braille dot) to retain the "blankness" of the region.  The kids seem to like it.

Comment: mkrieger1  re: The blind handling of Python whitespace:  As my students are very new to programming and Python, I can't say in general.  But my experience with the Braille software showed an interesting case of "Unintended consequences".  I am developing a "graphics to braille" TurtleBraille which renders simple Turtle output for blind viewing. (github raysmith619/resource_lib/readme.md)  The software compresses multiple blanks.  To avoid this, my software converts non-trailing blanks to commas(one braille dot) to retain the "blankness" of the region.  The kids seem to like it.

Comment: As far as handling Pythons whitespace:  The major screen readers I know of: JAWS and NVDA both have options which give audio feedback when the indent level changes - This aids editing in a number of applications such as PyCharm, Notepad, and VSCODE.  I'm currently suggesting VSCODE for my blind students because of VSCODE's better handling of program running for the blind.